# Creating zero-to-many entity relationships in ASP.NET Core with Entity Framework Core 7

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have been stuck for a couple of days trying to figure out how to create a zero-to-many relationship between two tables using an associative table using ASP.NET Core 6 and Entity Framework Core 7 (code-first). I'd appreciate any help!

For background, the models include two tables called `Queue` and `Agent`. A queue can be associated with many agents and an agent can be associated with one or more queues. Furthermore, there are cases where an existing queue is not associated with any agents (it is newly defined and has not been deployed yet or has been deactivated). The same is true for an agent; they will generally be associated with at least one queue but there are cases where they may be associated with none.

In my models, I have created three entities: one for `Queue`, `Agent`, and `AgentQueue` respectively. See code below.

Agent model class:

```cs
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

namespace CscopeWFM.Models.Infrastructure
{
    public class Agent
    {
        [Key]
        public int AgentID { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("AgentGroup")]
        public int? AgentGroupID { get; set; }

        public virtual AgentGroup? AgentParams { get; set; }

        [StringLength(100)]
        [Column(TypeName = "varchar (100)")]
        public string? AgentName { get; set; }

        [StringLength(100)]
        [Column(TypeName = "varchar (100)")]
        public string? AgentEmail { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        [Column(TypeName = "varchar (50)")]
        public string? AgentType { get; set; }
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        [Column(TypeName = "varchar (50)")]
        public string? EmployType { get; set; }
        public DateTime HireDate { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        [Column(TypeName = "varchar (50)")]
        public string? AgentLevel { get; set; }

        public List<AgentQueue>? AgentQueues { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Queue model class:

```cs
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

namespace CscopeWFM.Models.Infrastructure
{
    public class Queue
    {
        [Key]
        public int QueueID { get; set; }

        [StringLength(100)]
        [Column(TypeName = "varchar (100)")]
        public string? QueueType { get; set; }

        [StringLength(100)]
        [Column(TypeName = "varchar (100)")]
        public string? QueueName { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        [Column(TypeName = "varchar (50)")]
        public string? QueueChannel { get; set; }
        public bool? QueueActive { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        [Column(TypeName = "varchar (50)")]
        public string? Language { get; set; }
        public float? ServiceTarget { get; set; }
        public int? AnswerTarget { get; set; }
        public bool? IsActive { get; set; }

        public List<AgentQueue>? AgentQueues { get; set; }
    }
}
```

AgentQueue model class:

```cs
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

namespace CscopeWFM.Models.Infrastructure
{
    public class AgentQueue
    {
        public int? AgentID { get; set; }
        public Agent? Agent { get; set; }

        public int? QueueID { get; set; }
        public Queue? Queue { get; set; }
    }
}
```

In my context class, I have created an override to handle the `OnModelCreating` as shown here:

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<AgentQueue>()
                .HasKey(aq => new { aq.AgentID, aq.QueueID });

    modelBuilder.Entity<AgentQueue>()
                .HasOne(aq => aq.Agent)
                .WithMany(a => a.AgentQueues)
                .HasForeignKey(aq => aq.AgentID);

    modelBuilder.Entity<AgentQueue>()
                .HasOne(aq => aq.Queue)
                .WithMany(q => q.AgentQueues)
                .HasForeignKey(aq => aq.QueueID);
}
```

Everything is migrating fine and the tables appear to be created properly when I update the database. So far so good...

I have API Controllers that are being used to access these entities which were working fine until I realized that I needed the additional constraints.  Now, with the code shown above, the Post and Update methods for AddAgent and AddQueue are not working.  Same issue with Patch methods to update those entities.  I also created a new API Controller for AgentQueue so that I could "easily" create and maintain the relationships between agent and queue and only the GetAgentQueue (HTTP Get) method is working.

I can provide the code for the API controllers if that would help but I think the issue is probably with the model classes and/or DbContext. It seems like it is not letting me create any of the entities individually (e.g. create an agent without creating an association to one or more queues).

Any help would be appreciated. Seriously stuck.

Many thanks!

I have tried a number of different ways to define the DbContext OnModelCreating method but always get the same result in the end.

I need to be able to define Agents and Queues independently and then define a relationship between them separately.  I also need to have the ability to update/change and/or delete the relationship (entry in AgentQueue table) over time.

The Agent API controller code is shown below.  The Queue and AgentQueue controllers are set up with basically the same code.

Agent API controller:

```cs
using CscopeWFM.Models.Forecasting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using CscopeWFM.Models.Infrastructure;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace CscopeWFM.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class AgentController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly CSWFMDbContext _CSWFMDbContext;

        public AgentController(CSWFMDbContext CSWFMDbContext)
        {
            _CSWFMDbContext = CSWFMDbContext;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("GetAgent")]
        public async Task<IEnumerable<Agent>> GetAgents()
        {
            return await _CSWFMDbContext.Agent.ToListAsync();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [Route("AddAgent")]
        public async Task<Agent> AddAgent(Agent objAgent)
        {
            _CSWFMDbContext.Agent.Add(objAgent);
            await _CSWFMDbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
            return objAgent;
        }

        [HttpPatch]
        [Route("UpdateAgent/{AgentID}")]
        public async Task<Agent> UpdateAgent(Agent ObjAgent)
        {
            _CSWFMDbContext.Entry(ObjAgent).State = EntityState.Modified;
            await _CSWFMDbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
            return ObjAgent;
        }

        [HttpDelete]
        [Route("DeleteAgent/{AgentID}")]
        public bool DeleteAgent(int AgentID)
        {
            bool a = false;

            var agent = _CSWFMDbContext.Agent.Find(AgentID);

            if (agent != null)
            {
                a = true;
                _CSWFMDbContext.Entry(agent).State = EntityState.Deleted;
                _CSWFMDbContext.SaveChanges();
            }
            else
            {
                a = false;
            }

            return a;
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the app in debug and attempt to add an agent using the AddAgent method, this is basically what I see (screenshot below, post execute)

[API Response to AddAgent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZbId.png)

As you can see in the AddAgent, it seems to be expecting me to define the agentqueues as a part of the request.

Comment: " the Post and Update methods for AddAgent and AddQueue are not working" what's the error message you get ? Could you provide code about that ? If you added minimal reproducible example, and share it via gihub , it would be easier to tell.

Comment: Thank you for responding!  I have provided the code for the Agent API controller below. The one for Queue and AgentQueue are essentially the same.

Comment: I have updated the question to include the Agent Controller code and the response I am getting back when i attempt to execute the AddAgent method of the API.

Comment: I could be totally wrong, but I think that since I've defined the AgentQueue in onModelCreating as ".HasOne", it is expecting that there is going to be an entry in the AgentQueue table for every agent and/or Queue.  I thought that there might be a ".HasOptional" option but there does not appear to be.

Answer (score -1):

From your error message , I try to make some change as below,  you can refer to it, hope it help you.

1. Try to remove `<Nullable>enable</Nullable>` from your project file
   (double-click the project name or right-click the project to choose Edit Project File).

2.Add below code in the Program.cs to avoid System.Text.Json.JsonException: A possible object cycle.

```
builder.Services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(options =>
{
    options.JsonSerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.IgnoreCycles;
    
});
```

3.Modify you request body(remove   `"agent": "string",`     `, "agentQueues": [ "string" ]` ), because 400 error means:The syntax of the client's request is incorrect and the server cannot understand it.
The full request body like:

```
{
  "agentID": 0,
  "agentGroupID": 0,
  "agentParams": {
    "agentGroupID": 0,
    "groupName": "string",
    "grouptType": "string",
    "isActive": true
  },
  "agentName": "a4",
  "agentEmail": "string",
  "agentType": "string",
  "isActive": true,
  "employType": "string",
  "hireDate": "2023-06-01T06:38:20.507Z",
  "agentLevel": "string",
  "agentQueues": [
    {
      "agentID": 0,
      
      "queueID": 0,
      "queue": {
        "queueID": 0,
        "queueType": "string",
        "queueName": "string",
        "queueChannel": "string",
        "queueActive": true,
        "language": "string",
        "serviceTarget": 0,
        "answerTarget": 0,
        "isActive": true
        
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

result:
[image]